# Exporting tensorflow contrib.learn export to export to tensorfow_serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to export a an instance of `tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` for tensorflow serving. When running the following code:

```
estimator.export(
export_path,
signature_fn=tf.contrib.learn.utils.export.classification_signature_fn)
```

I get the following warning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Calling export (from
>   tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with
>   use_deprecated_input_fn=True is deprecated and will be removed after
>   2016-09-23.   Instructions for updating: The signature of the input_fn
>   accepted by export is changing to be consistent with what's used by
>   tf.Learn Estimator's train/evaluate. input_fn and input_feature_key
>   will become required args, and use_deprecated_input_fn will default to
>   False and be removed altogether.

The question is, can I ignore this warning for now? Another question, how would I write the code for the client? How do I prepare the protobuf correctly?

I see that for the mnist client they prepare the `protobuf` as follows:

```
request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'mnist'
image, label = test_data_set.next_batch(1)
request.inputs['images'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(image[0], shape=[1, image[0].size]))
```

How would I do the same for feature columns used in a `contrib.learn` estimator? For example, if the feature columns are as follows?

```
  country = sparse_column_with_vocabulary_file("country", VOCAB_FILE)
  age = real_valued_column("age")
  click_bucket = bucketized_column(real_valued_column("historical_click_ratio"),
                                   boundaries=[i/10. for i in range(10)])
  country_x_click = crossed_column([country, click_bucket], 10)
  feature_columns = set([age, click_bucket, country_x_click])
```

...and the `input_fn` from one of the tutorial such as https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide/index.html will provide the actual data to send from the client

Update:

I got an export/client combination running, but the results look wrong. Part of the export code is as follows:

```
def my_classification_signature_fn(examples, unused_features, predictions):
  """Creates classification signature from given examples and predictions.
  Args:
    examples: `Tensor`.
    unused_features: `dict` of `Tensor`s.
    predictions: `Tensor` or dict of tensors that contains the classes tensor
      as in {'classes': `Tensor`}.
  Returns:
    Tuple of default classification signature and empty named signatures.
  Raises:
    ValueError: If examples is `None`.
  """
  if examples is None:
    raise ValueError('examples cannot be None when using this signature fn.')

  if isinstance(predictions, dict):
    default_signature = exporter.classification_signature(
        examples, classes_tensor=predictions['classes'])
  else:
    print examples
    print predictions
    default_signature = exporter.classification_signature(
        examples, classes_tensor=predictions)
  named_graph_signatures={
        'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'x_values': examples}),
        'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'preds': predictions})}    
  return default_signature, named_graph_signatures

def export_input_fn(df,feature_defs,batch_size):
    input_features = input_fn(df, feature_defs)
    input_features["input_feature_dummy"] = tf.constant(np.array([["__SOME_VAL__" for __ in range(len(df.columns))] for _ in range(batch_size) ]),
                                      dtype=tf.string,
                                      shape=[batch_size, len(df.columns)])
    return input_features,None

model.export(
    "export_8",
    input_fn=lambda : export_input_fn(extdf,training_run_data["features"],20),
    input_feature_key="input_feature_dummy",
    signature_fn=my_classification_signature_fn,
    use_deprecated_input_fn=False)
```

And part of the client code is as follows:

```
pred_df = pd.read_csv("{}/client_test.csv".format(work_dir)).sort_index(axis=1)
host, port = hostport.split(':')
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
result_counter = _ResultCounter(num_tests, concurrency)


x_values = numpy.array([["__SOME_VAL__" for __ in range(len(pred_df.columns))] for _ in range(20)])
labels = pred_df["__label"].values
input_values = pred_df.astype('str').values
input_size = min(20, input_values.shape[0])
x_values[0:input_size] = input_values[0:input_size]

labels_test = numpy.zeros(20)
labels_test[0:input_size] = labels[0:input_size]

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'capture_process'

request.inputs['x_values'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(x_values, shape=x_values.shape))


result_counter.throttle()
result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds

result_future.add_done_callback(
    _create_rpc_callback(labels_test, result_counter))
```

As you can see I am trying to send all the input columns extracted from a pandas dataframe as one tensor proto called `x_values`. Is this correct or should I create an input for every feature column?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore that warning for now. The prediction API is a raw API where you feed in one or more tensor and get an output. So you have to run that part of the client which makes it a tensor, so yes, including the parameterization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now have an export and client running, but results still looks wrong. I am sending just one proto created from a 2d array of strings (from a pandas df) as an input. Or should I send one proto for every feature column?

Comment: You should send the whole tensor for a single example in one shot. There's no really good example of how to test a model side-by-side, so you have to more or less go by trial and error. I would print input/output values to debug.

Comment: Ok got that. I also just realized that I need to somehow transform the input data (that is a dict of tensors from the input_fn used in the fit method) to a single tensor. I looked at the python predict method and it seems like feature_column_ops.input_from_feature_columns will do this. Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Another question: Does predict_impl.cc build the whole graph - including the parts that handle high level feature columns or only the core network? If the latter, then I will have to run the parts of the graph that create the network inputs in the client - losing a lot of the scale that serving is supposed to provide. Correct?

Comment: The model exporter exports the whole graph (if you ask it to), or whatever is required to run inference, but the problem is mapping from high-level wrappers to the low-level operations to figure out exactly what you want. You'd have to traverse down the code to see what they wrappers actually do.

Comment: OK after extensive code traversal I have come to the conclusion that for now the use of tensorflow serving precludes the use of fancy feature column as created in the input_fn parameter  of the estimators fit/evaluate/predict methods because the graph needs to be built every time you provide inputs via the input_fn parameter and I dont see how that can work in tf serving. I will have to write my own code to replace the functionality of the feature columns (categoricals/embeddings) and provide inputs to the estimator via the 'x' and 'y' parameters of fit/evaluate/predict.

Comment: Could you file an issue on our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page to track a feature requiest?

Comment: I have read your client code so should I replace 'tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(x_values, shape=x_values.shape)' by 'feature_column_ops.input_from_feature_columns' to create a tensor?